# How to fix: Starting services stored in variables

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to make a script which does the following:

1. Get the services which are running
2. Get all services with startup type automatic, which arent running
3. Start all services which aren't running, but got startup type automatic.

The script will be run on different windows servers. I already tried to compare the services which should run (`$servicestorun`), to the one actually running (`$servicesrunning`), and then start the ones who aren't running but should.

Can someone here point me to the right direction or provide me with code needed to fix it?

```
$servicesrunning = Get-Service | Where {
     $_.StartUpType –eq 'automatic' -and $_.Status –eq 'running'
} # gets running services
$servicestorun = Get-Service | Where {
    $_.StartUpType –eq 'automatic' -and
    $_.Status –eq 'stopped'
} # gets services with startup type automatic and status stopped

# checks if all services which should run, actually run
if ($servicestorun -eq $servicesrunning) {
    echo "all good" # if positive, message all good then exit
    exit
} else {
    Start-Service $servicestorun # starts all services with startup type automatic and status stopped 
}
```

And the error I'm getting:

> Start-Service : Das Argument für den Parameter "InputObject" kann nicht überprüft werden.

Comment: You have 2 lists: a list of services that are running, and a list of services that are supposed to be running, but aren't. Under which circumstances will those two lists be the same?

Comment: A service can't be 'automatic' and 'stopped' at the same time.  I think you want '-or'.  Plus, -eq acts differently with an array on the left side.  I don't think it's doing what you want.  "$servicestorun -eq $servicesrunning"

Comment: The most likely reason for the error is that `$servicestorun` is empty.

Comment: @js2010 Of course it can. Just because a service is configured for automatic start on system startup doesn't mean it's currently running (it could for instance have crashed, or the admin could have stopped it for some reason).

Comment: I might should have wrote more about that:

We got a few servers in our network, which (after a reboot), won't start a few services, eventho they are set to starting-type automatic. 

I want to "compare" those lists, and start every service, which has starting-type automatic, but isnt started.. I guess -and is the wrong attribute here? 

Maybe this way would be better?:
If service startuptype is automatic, and service-status IS NOT running then start service - but how do I do that in Powershell? Btw edited the code in the initialpost...

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sorry, I thought it was the same property.

Comment: @SamuelKlose Please take a step back and think: when will a list of services that are running and a list of services that are *not* running be equal?

Comment: You can't compare 2 arrays with -eq like that.  You can try compare-object, but the result is kind of backwards.  $null if they're the same, and not $null if something is different.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers no they won't lel, that's why I fixed the code above...

Comment: @SamuelKlose You still don't get it. Even after your edit the two lists are mutually exclusive, meaning they'll *never* be equal. Also, as js2010 meintioned, arrays can't be compared like that in the first place. For these 2 reasons your check will always evaluate to "false" and the code will always jump to the `else` branch. *Even if the list of services to start is empty!*

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers of course I don't get it, else I wouldn't ask here.

Comment: Just run everything in $servicestorun

Comment: I doubt the reasons for failing services are that easily solved, but simply pipe `$servicestorun | Start-Service`

Comment: Break it down piece by piece, and make sure each piece works.

Comment: Couldn't I like cut down the script anyways and just do like: $services= Get-Service which is automatic but not running and then Start-Service $services?

Comment: Sure...........

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison will always evaluate to "false" for 2 reasons:

- PowerShell arrays are objects, and the `-eq` operator tests for identity of the objects, not if both array objects contain the same elements.
- The two lists you're comparing are mutually exclusive, so even if you could compare the arrays using the `-eq` operator (which, again, you can't) the result would *still* be "false".

Because of that your code will always jump to the `else` branch, even if there are no services to start. In that situation you'll pass an empty variable to `Start-Service`, which results in the error you observed.

Since you want to start all services that are configured for automatic start, but aren't currently running, simply use the pipeline:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {
    $_.StartUpType –eq 'automatic' -and
    $_.Status –ne 'running'
} | Start-Service
```